# SQL ERROR HELP Column 'customer.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID' is invalid group by issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to get a list of all members with the latest order date, but unfortunately I keep getting the following error.  Please help as I'm fairly a new sql programmer.

I keep getting the following error

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Column 'customer.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID' is invalid in the select list 
because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or 
the GROUP BY clause.
```

The query is:-

```
select DISTINCT
    c.master_customer_id,
    c.first_name,
    c.last_name,
    c.label_name,
    c.primary_email_address,
    ca.address_1,
    ca.CITY,
    ca.POSTAL_CODE,
    ca.COUNTRY_CODE,
    ca.COUNTRY_DESCR,
    ca.FORMATTED_ADDRESS,
    od.PRODUCT_CODE,
    od.LINE_STATUS_CODE,
    od.INITIAL_BEGIN_DATE,
    DATEDIFF(YY,INITIAL_BEGIN_DATE,GETDATE()) as YEARS,
    MAX(OD.ORDER_DATE) AS LATEST_ORDER     
from 
    cus_current_membership_info mb
    inner join customer c
        on mb.master_customer_id = c.master_customer_id
        and mb.sub_customer_id = c.sub_customer_id
    inner join CUS_ADDRESS_DETAIL cad
              on c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = cad.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
              and c.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = cad.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID   
              and cad.PRIORITY_SEQ = 0
    inner join  cus_address ca
              on cad.CUS_ADDRESS_ID = ca.CUS_ADDRESS_ID    
    inner join order_detail od
              on od.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
              and od.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = c.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID                       
where     
       c.CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE = 'INDIV'
       and c.CUSTOMER_STATUS_CODE = 'ACTIVE'
    and c.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL
    and LINE_STATUS_CODE = 'A'
    and SUBSYSTEM = 'MBR'
    and PRODUCT_CODE IN ('AFF','E','H','PD','PDM','PDRL','PDRM','PDRU',
    'R','RM','RRL','RRM ','RRU','S','SM','SRL','SRM',
    'SRU','SU','SUM','SURL','SURM','SURU','TFL')
    and INITIAL_BEGIN_DATE <= dateadd(year,-25,getdate())     
GROUP BY OD.ORDER_DATE
```

Comment: You are grouping by one column and yet selecting zillions of others.  The intention of your query is unclear, but you can add all the non-aggregated columns to the `group by` to fix the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your group by should have this list

```
GROUP BY c.master_customer_id,
    c.first_name,
    c.last_name,
    c.label_name,
    c.primary_email_address,
    ca.address_1,
    ca.CITY,
    ca.POSTAL_CODE,
    ca.COUNTRY_CODE,
    ca.COUNTRY_DESCR,
    ca.FORMATTED_ADDRESS,
    od.PRODUCT_CODE,
    od.LINE_STATUS_CODE,
    od.INITIAL_BEGIN_DATE,
    DATEDIFF(YY,INITIAL_BEGIN_DATE,GETDATE())
```

Row_Number() function to get last record for each customer

```
;WITH CTE 
AS (
select  c.master_customer_id,
        c.first_name,
        c.last_name,
        c.label_name,
        c.primary_email_address,
        ca.address_1,
        ca.CITY,
        ca.POSTAL_CODE,
        ca.COUNTRY_CODE,
        ca.COUNTRY_DESCR,
        ca.FORMATTED_ADDRESS,
        od.PRODUCT_CODE,
        od.LINE_STATUS_CODE,
        od.INITIAL_BEGIN_DATE,
        DATEDIFF(YY,INITIAL_BEGIN_DATE,GETDATE()) as YEARS,
        OD.ORDER_DATE  LATEST_ORDER,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  c.master_customer_id ORDER BY OD.ORDER_DATE DESC) rn
from  cus_current_membership_info mb
inner join customer c  on mb.master_customer_id = c.master_customer_id
                      and mb.sub_customer_id = c.sub_customer_id
inner join CUS_ADDRESS_DETAIL cad
                      on c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = cad.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
                     and c.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = cad.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID   
                     and cad.PRIORITY_SEQ = 0
inner join  cus_address ca
                    on cad.CUS_ADDRESS_ID = ca.CUS_ADDRESS_ID
inner join order_detail od
                    on od.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
                   and od.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = c.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID
where c.CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE = 'INDIV'
    and c.CUSTOMER_STATUS_CODE = 'ACTIVE'
    and c.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL
    and LINE_STATUS_CODE = 'A'
    and SUBSYSTEM = 'MBR'
    and PRODUCT_CODE IN ('AFF','E','H','PD','PDM','PDRL','PDRM','PDRU',
    'R','RM','RRL','RRM ','RRU','S','SM','SRL','SRM',
    'SRU','SU','SUM','SURL','SURM','SURU','TFL')
    and INITIAL_BEGIN_DATE <= dateadd(year,-25,getdate()) 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```